# Alocar espaço para um vetor de vetor de vetor de double

Tags: array, c++, alocação

Estou tentando alocar espaço na memória para um vetor de vetor de vetor de double. Sei que para um vetor de vetor eu posso fazer

```
vector<vector<double>>  Vetor(51, vector<double>(47, 1))
```

E isso me gera um vetor[51][47] mas no caso de vetor de vetor de vetor essa definição não fica tão clara. Existe alguma possibilidade de alocação para esse outro caso?

Comment: Cara, não entendi bem a tua dúvida... tu queres fazer isso -> `vector<vector<vector<double>>>`? Não sei o que é tua classe Vetor... E vector tem alocação dinâmica, tu queres definir um tamanho inicial, para cada dimensão?

Comment: isso, preciso fazer um vector<vector<vector<double>>> nome  e para isso preciso alocar espaço na memória como fiz no caso do texto principal com um vector<vector<double>>. pois alocando espaço na memoria eu posso alimentar nome[i][j][k] sem usar pushback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu poderias fazer da seguinte forma:

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> v(WIDTH);
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    v[i].resize(HEIGHT);
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
        v[i][j].resize(DEPTH);
```

Assim, teu vetor seria `v[WIDTH][HEIGHT][DEPTH]`. É uma opção que talvez fique mais clara do que aninhar tudo em vários parênteses...

Outra opção, similar, seria, em vez de usar o método `resize`, usar o método `reserve` para setar a capacidade inicial de cada dimensão.